# Azure live cost monitoring

Tags: azure

In my Azure environment I am often tinkering around, adding new services, scaling roles up and down, etc.  The problem is that I am always unsure as to how I may have affected my monthly bill.  I'm also scared of forgetting to kill services after I don't need them (for example, I mistakenly had a Reporting Service running for a few weeks - very expensive!).

I'm looking for an add-on or service which can give be a basic idea of how much money I am consuming in Azure.  I don't need something complicated.  A graph or two could be great (perhaps a burn down).

**I found these but without luck:**

- [Foglight for Azure](http://www.foglight-on-demand.com/content/en/index.html):  This didn't work for me.  All my figures showed up as 0.
- [Active Cloud Monitoring](http://www.raythos.com/cloud/active-cost-monitoring-for-windows-azure):  This has been removed from the Azure add-ons.

Does anyone know of such a solution?

Comment: Try this Windows 8 app: http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/12/27/introducing-azure-ticker-app-for-windows-8/. I'm not sure it has been kept up-to-date though.

Comment: Gaurav: Seems to have been removed.

Comment: I'm able to see it in Windows Store: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/azure-ticker/bb2d4576-1b2c-4d65-8a86-b146d17a4f05. Also the source code is available on Github as well: https://github.com/AppliedIS/AzureTicker. HTH.

Comment: You can use the Azure Cost Monitor which is focused on Azure EA customers https://costs.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 20, accepted):

thank you for the question and the feedback. The new Azure portal, which is currently in public preview, does have this feature. You can try out the new portal at https://portal.azure.com/ . Once there, click on Billing tab on the left of the screen, which should bring up a billing summary for all your subscriptions. Click on the subscription that you need to check, and that will show you the billing details for that subscription. Details include subscription status, days left, current charges, burn down, and a breakdown of current charges by resource.

Please try this out and send your feedback using the "Give feedback" link at the top of the new portal page. You will have to click on your account name to see the "Give feedback" option in the drop down.

Comment: This is not true anymore. You have to go to https://account.windowsazure.com, there select your subscription and there you will see how much money you have spent.

Comment: https://portal.azure.com and account.windowsazure.com both can get you this info (both the parent and the comment are correct).  I personally hit the portal, as that's where I do most of my work on Azure

Comment: portal.azure.com has the billing graph, the only thing I'm not a fan of is the update frequency. You can see you're burning too much cash then make some adjustments, but the graph doesn't update for what seems like 24 hours. So whether or not your changes will hit your target you can't really get quick answers to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "Enterprise Agreement" as a billing option, the Azure portal does not provide sufficient billing information.

You could use [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/) to import the data from Azure and use it for reporting. In Power BI you can use the Content pack "Microsoft Azure Enterprise" and connect it to your subscription. You will need the Enrollment number for your Enterprise Agreement and an API key to access the data.

A detailed explanation can be found in this [blog entry](http://techgenix.com/azure-enterprise-costs-power-bi/).